# mongodb fails to start in opensuse

Tags: mongodb

I followed this to install and start mongodb in openSUSE: https://en.opensuse.org/MongoDB

Also created a btrfs subvolume with mongodb directory, all good.

However, when I run `systemctl status mongodb`, i get this error:

```
Job for mongodb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mongodb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then, I run `systemctl status mongodb.service`, i get:

```
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor pr>
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-10-09 19:41:36 EDT; 18s ago
  Process: 31299 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mongod -f $CONFIG $OPTIONS (code=exited, s>
```

More details, i run `journalctl -xe`:

```
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: WinId of the >
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Trying again
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: REQUEST
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Request:  "Pa>
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: "Password: "
Oct 09 19:41:31 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Dialog accept>
Oct 09 19:41:31 ryzen-pc polkit-agent-helper-1[31292]: gkr-pam: unable to locat>
Oct 09 19:41:31 ryzen-pc polkit-agent-helper-1[31292]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth):>
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: COMPLETED
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Completed:  f>
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Finishing obt>
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Trying again
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: REQUEST
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Request:  "Pa>
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: "Password: "
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Dialog accept>
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-agent-helper-1[31294]: gkr-pam: unable to locat>
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: COMPLETED
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Completed:  t>
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Finishing obt>
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Listener adap>
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: polkit_qt_lis>
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Finish obtain>
lines 1286-1308/1308 (END)
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: WinId of the shown dialog is  33554461 33554461
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Trying again
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: REQUEST
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Request:  "Password: "
Oct 09 19:41:29 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: "Password: "
Oct 09 19:41:31 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Dialog accepted
Oct 09 19:41:31 ryzen-pc polkit-agent-helper-1[31292]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Oct 09 19:41:31 ryzen-pc polkit-agent-helper-1[31292]:  pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000  euid=0 tty= ruser=root rhost=  user=root
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: COMPLETED
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Completed:  false
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Finishing obtaining privileges
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Trying again
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: REQUEST
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Request:  "Password: "
Oct 09 19:41:33 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: "Password: "
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Dialog accepted
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-agent-helper-1[31294]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: COMPLETED
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Completed:  true
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Finishing obtaining privileges
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]:  Listener adapter polkit_qt_listener_initiate_authentication_finish
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]:  polkit_qt_listener_initiate_authentication_finish callback for   0x55afc7e206a0
Oct 09 19:41:36 ryzen-pc polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[3702]: Finish obtain authorization: true
```

I tried googling but no avail. Any idea what's going on?
Thanks.

Comment: Does https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-suse/ help?

Comment: Try to isolate the messages from MongoDB only (`journalctl -xe -u mongodb`). Also, does MongoDB log in `/var/log/mongodb` show something?

Comment: @TomášLinhart shows "no entries", that's it. Also, I cannot access the mongodb in /log because permission denied. But it's empty in /var/lib/mongodb